# How to influence background color when I use NSView.dataWithPDF(inside:)

Tags: cocoa, macos-darkmode

I cannot translate the DarkAqua appearance into a PDF right now. The resulting document uses a white background color. But that removes visibility of white elements in the view (which I use as part of dark mode).

I was able to influence JPG creation by providing a backgroundcolor. How do I do the same for PDF creation?